# How to bind Azure Function to a blob container in Python?

Tags: python, azure

I have a blob container containing multiple files. I'm interested in binding the last modified one as input for an azure function. The function is implemented in python.

I thought I could do this by binding a blob container as CloudBlobContainer and then iterate over the files to find the last modified one. According to [this thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/26479) it seems like binding to a container is possible in C#. But I can't figure out how to do this in Python. CloudBlobContainer doesn't seem to exist for Python. What other alternatives do I have?

Comment: not sure if you have seen this article, but you can use blob input bindings https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python#example

Comment: Thanks Manish, I believe I did see that article as well, but it doesn't really cover my case. My function is triggered by a HTTP request, and sure, I can bind a blob there, but I have no way (I'm aware of) of binding the last modified blob. That's why I want to bind the blob container so I can look for the latest modified blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to this thread it seems like binding to a container is
>   possible in C#.

It seems that you have already seen the [Usage of Blob Trigger Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=csharp#usage) document.Another evidence is that,actually,all bindings of dev language platform except C# are built on the [ExtensionBundle](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-extension-bundles/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/extensions.json).You could see there is no Container type in the supported list.

[image]

So, i guess you have to implement it with python blob storage sdk in the Azure Function method. Or you could submit feedback to Azure Function Team to improve the product.